# Can the Daily 24 hour be configured to not start at 0000 UTC

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

When using security("BYBIT:BTCUSD", "D", volume) - the 24 hours of volume data captured start from UTC 00:00.

Is there a way to change this so that the data captured could start from 1200 UTC for 24 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do it.
You just add up the current and previous 12H (=720 minutes) volume.

```
//@version=4
study("Test", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

v = security("BYBIT:BTCUSD", "720", volume) 

v_sum = v + v[1]

plot(v_sum, style=plot.style_histogram)
```